# It or them/these?

Tags: grammar

Be aware that formatting the pendrive or the flash card will erase any data stored on it.

Should the last word be "it" or "them/these"? I opted for "it" given the pendrive and flash card are separated by "or" rather than "and", but I'm still unsure.

Comment: 'will erase any stored data.'

Comment: Did you introduce a specific pen drive and flash card in a previous sentence? If not, then avoid definite articles.  Use _"formatting **a** pen drive or **a** flash card will erase any data stored on **it**"_

Comment: singular OR singular. Therefore, singular "it"

Comment: Be aware that formatting the pendrive or the flash card will erase any data stored on the device.

Comment: Edwin, simple but effective, I like it. Curious proofreader and aparente001 both tell me that the rules of logic are applied, that is, a singular OR singular should take a subsequent singular pronoun, which is great for future reference. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might have avoided the concern with:  .....stored thereon.

Comment: John, it is best not to answer a question that is on a quick road to getting closed, as this one is (due to it being a proofreading question, or perhaps because the author didn't share any research or attempts to figure it out before posting).

Comment: Hi, I did explain my reasoning for using "it".

Comment: I think I like this answer most John M.